# Long MySQL statements with OR in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a noob question but I didn't found any answer on the web, because this is some special issue I think. I'm programming a message system with auto refreshing.

This is for getting the latest ID in the db:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` 
                          WHERE `requestor`='".$_POST['user_id']."' 
                          AND `target`='".$_POST['target_id']."' 
                          OR `requestor`='".$_POST['target_id']."' 
                          AND `target`='".$_POST['user_id']."' 
                          ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id = $rows['id'];      //latest message id at this moment

$lastSeenID = $_POST['msg_id'];     //This is the latest id which is shown on the client
```

Now I need the columns where the IDs are bigger than the last known id on the client. ($lastSeenID).

But this isn't going to work the right way.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` 
             WHERE `id` > '".$lastSeenID."' 
             AND `requestor`='".$_POST['user_id']."' 
             AND `target`='".$_POST['target_id']."' 
             OR `requestor`='".$_POST['target_id']."' 
             AND `target`='".$_POST['user_id']."' 
             ORDER BY `id` ASC")
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Parentheses are your friend

Comment: hey yo stop using mysql it's deprecated yo and then fix your holes cause they'll blow up your code yo.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Hey yo, I sure hope you don't speak like that in public yo, even though you're right yo :P

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ain't nobody got time fo dat

Comment: Where you get a solution yourself, please post that in an answer box and tick it, rather than adding it to the question. I'll do this one this time around. Also: there's quite a few SQL injection opportunities here - if you want your website to remain up, I suggest you fix that `;-)`.

Comment: @halfer The data is posted by ajax in the background so ... I thought I don't need to escape the variables. But you are right I need to use mysql_real_escape_string() for every data. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of the OP.*

I got the working code (thanks for the advice with the parentheses).

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`id` > '".$lastSeenID."' AND `requestor`='".$_POST['user_id']."' AND `target`='".$_POST['target_id']."') OR (`id` > '".$lastSeenID."' AND `requestor`='".$_POST['target_id']."' AND `target`='".$_POST['user_id']."') ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

Answer (score 2):

Please start to like query parameters:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`id` > '$lastSeenID' AND `requestor`='$_POST['user_id']' AND `target`='$_POST['target_id']' OR `requestor`='$_POST['target_id']' AND `target`='$_POST['user_id']') ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

or MySQLi

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`id` > '$lastSeenID' AND `requestor`='$_POST['user_id']' AND `target`='$_POST['target_id']' OR `requestor`='$_POST['target_id']' AND `target`='$_POST['user_id']') ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

Comment: This doesnt work too. :/ I even got an error but I escaped it right. But I still got the same result as before :( But thanks for the advice with the Parentheses. -> Look at first post.

Comment: Just so you know, you've replicated the OP's SQL injection vulnerabilities here.

Comment: @hookieV2: each of the `$_POST['value']` values must be run through `my_real_escape_string`, otherwise your users can inject SQL of their own choosing. Even better is to drop the mysql library and to switch to something that supports parameterisation - do a search for "PDO parameterisation" or "mysqli parameterisation".